# Why does Deep Q Network outputs multiple Q values?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning, dqn, deep-rl, action-spaces

I am learning Deep RL following this tutorial: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/an-introduction-to-deep-q-learning-lets-play-doom-54d02d8017d8

I understand everything but one detail:

This image shows the difference between a classic Q learning table and a DNN.
It states that a Q table needs a state-action pair as input and outputs the corresponding Q value whereas a Deep Q network needs the state as feature input and outputs the Q value for each action that can be made in that state.

But shouldn't the state AND the action together be the input to the network and the network just outputs a single Q value?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this was just a "clever" design choice. You can actually design a neural network (NN), to represent your Q function, which receives as input the state and an action and outputs the corresponding Q value. However, to obtain $\max_aQ(s', a)$ (which is a term of the update rule of the [Q-learning algorithm](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/10560/2444)) you would need a "forward pass" of this network for each possible action from $s'$. By having a NN that outputs the Q value for each possible action from a given $s'$, you will just need one forward pass of the NN to obtain $\max_aQ(s', a)$, that is, you pick the highest Q value among the outputs of your NN.

In the paper [A Brief Survey of Deep Reinforcement Learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.05866.pdf) (by Kai Arulkumaran, Marc Peter Deisenroth, Miles Brundage and Anil Anthony Bharath), at page 7, section "Value functions" (and subsection "Function Approximation and the DQN"), it's written

> It was designed such that the final fully connected layer outputs $Q^\pi(s,\cdot)$ for all action values in a discrete set of actions — in this case, the various directions of the joystick and the fire button. This not only enables the best action, $\text{argmax}_a Q^\pi(s, a)$, to be chosen after a single forward pass of the network, but also allows the network to more easily encode action-independent knowledge in the lower, convolutional layers.