# What is a generalized MDP?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, reference-request, definitions, markov-decision-process

What is a generalized MDP?

Here are a few sub-questions.

1. How is it different than a "regular" MDP?
2. How does it generalize the notion of an MDP?
3. Why do we need a generalized MDP?
4. Do generalized MDPs have some practical usefulness or they are just theoretical tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This answer is based on info that you can find in the paper [$\varepsilon $-MDPs: Learning in Varying Environments](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume3/szita02a/html/Szita02a.html), 2002, by István Szita et al. and [[Szepesvári and Littman(1996)]](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Csaba-Szepesvari/publication/245451971_Generalized_Markov_Decision_Processes_Dynamic_programming_and_Reinforcement-le_arning_Algorithms/links/00b4952921789cfd76000000/Generalized-Markov-Decision-Processes-Dynamic-programming-and-Reinforcement-le-arning-Algorithms.pdf), the paper that proposed generalised MDPs. I just adapted the notation to be more consistent with [Sutton & Barto's book](http://incompleteideas.net/book/RLbook2020.pdf) and provided additional info and links).

#### What is an MDP?

Let's first start with the usual definition of an MDP.

An MDP is defined by the tuple $\langle \mathcal{S}, \mathcal{A}, R, \color{blue}{P} , \gamma \rangle$, where

- $\mathcal{S}$ is the set of states
- $\mathcal{A}$ is the set of actions
- $R: \mathcal{S} \times \mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{S} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the [reward function](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/10442/2444); so $R(s, a, s')$ is the reward for taking action $a \in \mathcal{A}$ in state $s \in \mathcal{S}$ and ending up in $s' \in \mathcal{S}$.
- $\color{blue}{P}: \mathcal{S} \times \mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{S} \rightarrow [0, 1]$ is the **transition model**; so $\color{blue}{P}(s, a, s')$ is the probability of arriving in state $s'$ after having taken action $a$ in the state $s$. You could also [define the transition model to include the reward](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/10442/2444), denoted by $\color{blue}{P}(s', r \mid s, a)$ to emphasize that it's a conditional probability distribution), but let's ignore this for now.
- $0 \leq \gamma < 1$ is a discount factor, which can be useful for infinite-horizon problems

Given this formulation of a decision problem, the goal is to maximize the expected reward. The objective function can be defined as follows
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \gamma^{t} R_{t} \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[ G_{t} \right],
$$
where $R_{t}$ is the reward that we get at [time step $t$](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/11605/2444).

There are multiple ways to solve this problem. The most common is probably Q-learning.

#### Q-learning

In Q-learning, we try to estimate the state-action (or action) value function. The optimal value function is defined as follows

$$
Q^{*}(s, a)=\sum_{s'} \color{blue}{P}(s, a, s')\left(R(s, a, s')+\gamma \color{red}{\max} _{a^{\prime}} Q^{*}(s', a^{\prime})\right) \label{1}\tag{1}, 
$$
for all $s \in \mathcal{S}$.

So, it's a function of the form $Q^{*}: \mathcal{S} \times \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. To emphasize the main purpose of this function, it can be denoted/defined as $Q^{*}(s, a) = \mathbb{E}\left[G_t \mid a, s \right]$, so it's the expected return ($G_t$ is the return or cumulative reward) for taking action $a$ in state $s$ under the optimal policy $\pi^*$ (hence the $*$).

The equation (\ref{1}) is a recursive equation because $Q^{*}(s, a)$ is defined in terms of itself, i.e. we use $Q^{*}(s', a^{\prime})$ to define it. In this context, this type of recursive equation is also known as [**Bellman equation**](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/11057/2444) (due to [Richard Bellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_E._Bellman), who contributed to the theory of dynamic programming, which is related to MDPs, as dynamic programming algorithms can be used to solve MDPs, given a transition model).

One thing to keep in mind is that the optimal policy can be derived from the optimal state-action value function by acting greedily with respect to it.

#### What is a Generalized MDP?

Now, there's one reason why I colored the transition model and the max operation in the Bellman equation \ref{1} in $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$ and $\color{red}{\text{red}}$, respectively, and this is related to generalized MDPs.

The Bellman equation in \ref{1} is defined with respect to

- the transition model $\color{blue}{P}$, which describes the dynamics of the environment,
- $\color{red}{\max}$, which is related to the assumption that the optimal agent acts greedily with respect to the optimal value function (keep in mind that the max operation is [non-expansive](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/11244/2444))

A **generalised MDP** [[Szepesvári and Littman(1996)]](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Csaba-Szepesvari/publication/245451971_Generalized_Markov_Decision_Processes_Dynamic_programming_and_Reinforcement-le_arning_Algorithms/links/00b4952921789cfd76000000/Generalized-Markov-Decision-Processes-Dynamic-programming-and-Reinforcement-le-arning-Algorithms.pdf) is a generalisation of multiple versions/definitions of MDPs that circulate around in the literature, including the definition above. More specifically, 2 concepts are generalised: transition model and the max operator.

Mathematically, we can define a generalised MDP as a tuple $\langle \mathcal{S}, \mathcal{A}, R, \color{blue}{\oplus}, \color{red}{\otimes}, \gamma \rangle$, where $\mathcal{S}, \mathcal{A}$ and $R$ are defined as above and

- $\color{blue}{\oplus}: (\mathcal{S} \times \mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{S} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}) \rightarrow(\mathcal{S} \times \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathbb{R})$ is a "**expected value-type**" operator that generalises $\color{blue}{P}$; the intuition of this operator is the same as the input of $\color{blue}{P}$ that I described above
- $\color{red}{\otimes}:(\mathcal{S} \times \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}) \rightarrow(\mathcal{S} \rightarrow \mathbb{R})$ is a "**maximization-type**" operator that generalises $\color{red}{\max}$; the intuition of $\color{red}{\otimes}$ is also the same as the intuition of $\color{red}{\max}$ (i.e. it represents how the optimal agent would behave).

So, these are [*operators*](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/20380/2444) (like the gradient operator or the [Bellman operator](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/11057/2444)) because they take as input a function and produce another function.

Now, if we set

- $(\color{blue}{\oplus} U)(s, a)=\sum_{s'} \color{blue}{P}(s, a, s') U(s, a, s')$ (so, in this case, it takes as input the function $U$; note that, in this case, $\color{blue}{\oplus}$ is an **expected value** operator, with respect to the probability distirbution $\color{blue}{P}(s, a, s')$)
- $(\color{red}{\otimes} Q)(s)=\color{red}{\max}_{a} Q(s, a)$ (note that this just uses the $\color{red}{\max}$)

Then we get the usual **expected-reward MDP model**.

#### What are the advantages of Generalised MDPs?

In the literature, there are **different versions of MDPs**, such as

- Markov games [[Littman(1994)]](https://courses.cs.duke.edu/spring07/cps296.3/littman94markov.pdf)
- alternating Markov games [[Boyan(1992)]](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.40.3103&rep=rep1&type=pdf)
- discounted expected-reward MDPs [[Watkins and Dayan(1992)]](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF00992698.pdf)
- risk-sensitive MDPs [[Heger(1994)]](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.45.8264&rep=rep1&type=pdf)
- exploration-sensitive MDPs [[John(1994)]](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.6.5630&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Generalised MDPs generalise all these MDPs for different values of $\color{blue}{\oplus}$ and $\color{red}{\otimes}$.

The paper [[Szepesvári and Littman(1996)]](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Csaba-Szepesvari/publication/245451971_Generalized_Markov_Decision_Processes_Dynamic_programming_and_Reinforcement-le_arning_Algorithms/links/00b4952921789cfd76000000/Generalized-Markov-Decision-Processes-Dynamic-programming-and-Reinforcement-le-arning-Algorithms.pdf) (that introduced GMDPs) provides more info about how we should set $\color{red}{\otimes}$ and $\color{blue}{\oplus}$ to get these different MDPs (see table 1).

#### Bellman equations in Generalised MDPs

The Bellman equation for the state value function can be expressed as follows in the context of GMDP

$$
V^{*}=\color{red}{\otimes} \color{blue}{\oplus} \left(R + \gamma V^{*}\right)
$$

For the state-action value function, you can have the following Bellman equation

$$
K Q=\color{blue}{\oplus} (R+\gamma \color{red}{\otimes} Q)
$$

or the one that relates $Q^{*}$ to $V^{*}$

$$
Q^{*}=\color{blue}{\oplus} \left(R+\gamma V^{*}\right)
$$