# Is there any difference between affine transformation and linear transformation?

Tags: neural-networks, terminology, pytorch, linear-algebra

Consider the following statements from [A Simple Custom Module](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/modules.html) of PyTorch's documentation

> To get started, let’s look at a simpler, custom version of PyTorch’s
> Linear module. This module applies an **affine transformation** to its
> input.

Since the paragraph is saying *PyTorch’s **Linear** module*, I am guessing that affine transformation is nothing but linear transformation.

Suppose $x = [x_1, x_2, x_3,\cdots,x_n]$ be an input, then the linear transformation on $x$ can be $a.x+b$, where $a$ and $b$ are $n-$ dimensional vectors of real numbers. And dot($.$) stands for dot product.

Is affine transformation same as the linear transformation? If yes, then why the name **affine** is used? Does it cover something more or less than linear transformation?

Answer (score 7):

In *linear algebra*, a [**linear transformation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map) (aka linear map or linear transform) $f: \mathcal{V} \rightarrow \mathcal{W}$ is a function that satisfies the following two conditions

1. $f(u + v)=f(u)+f(v)$ (additivity)
2. $f(\alpha u) = \alpha f(u)$ (scalar multiplication),

where

- $u$ and $v$ vectors (i.e. elements of a [vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space), which can also be $\mathbb{R}$ [[proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Real_Numbers_form_Vector_Space)], some space of functions, etc.)
- $\alpha$ is a scalar (e.g. which can be a real number, but not necessarily)
- $\mathcal{V}$ and $\mathcal{W}$ are vector spaces (e.g. $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}^2$)

So, any function that satisfies these two conditions is a linear transformation.

In *Euclidean geometry*, $g(x) = ax + b$ is an [**affine transformation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation), which is generally **not** a linear transformation as defined in linear algebra. You can easily show that affine transformations are not linear transformations. For example, let $a = 1$ and $b = 2$, does $g$ satisfy the second condition above for any scalar $\alpha$? No. For example, let $\alpha = 3$, then $g(3x = y) = y + 2 = 3x + 2 \neq 3 g(x) = 3 (x + 2) = 3x + 6$.

However, in the context of neural networks, when people use the adjective "linear" they are often referring to a line. For example, in linear regression, you can have a bias (the $b$ in the affine transformation $g$ above), which would make the function not a linear transformation, but we still call it linear regression because we fit a **line** (hence the name **line**ar regression) to the data.

So, no, an affine transformation is not a linear transformation as defined in linear algebra, but all linear transformations are affine. However, in machine learning, people often use the adjective linear to refer to straight-line models, which are generally represented by functions that are affine transformations. In [this answer](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/20380/2444), I also talk about this issue.

Comment: Ha, affine does not satisfying first property also.

Answer (score 4):

The fact is you can always express an affine transformation as a linear transformation (more convenient because it is just a matrix/dot product).

For instance, given an input $\textbf{x}=[x_1, ..., x_n]$, some weights $\textbf{a} = [a_1, a_2, ..., a_n]$ and a bias $b \in \mathbb{R}$, you can express the **affine** operation $y = \textbf{a}\cdot \textbf{x} + b$ as :

$y = \tilde{\textbf{a}} \cdot \tilde{\textbf{x}}$, with $\tilde{\textbf{a}} = [a_1, ..., a_n, b]$ and $\tilde{\textbf{x}} = [x_1, ..., x_n, 1]$ (**linear** operation)

When your affine transformation is a function $f:\mathbb{R}^p \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^q$ with $\textbf{y}=f(\textbf{x})=A\textbf{x} + \textbf{b}$, you can use the same trick (by adding a column with the biases at the right end of the weight matrix $A$), so you get: $\textbf{y}=\tilde{A}\tilde{\textbf{x}}$

I found an example [in this video](https://youtu.be/Q4GNLhRtZNc?t=398), where Andrew Ng uses this trick for a simple Linear Regression.