# Does the summing or averaging of the weight gradients have anything to do with the cost function used?

Tags: neural-networks, objective-functions, mini-batch-gradient-descent

I've been trying to implement my own neural network library and have been wondering if:

- The SSE loss function includes the summation of the errors in the other training examples of the mini-batch (each training example's loss in the mini-batch is summed for one big loss)
- The MSE loss function averages the loss of each individual training example in the mini-batch, and then all those losses are averaged based on the mini-batch size.

or if the summing or averaging of the weight gradients has nothing to do with the loss function used?

I feel like the answer would be clear if I knew other loss functions, if it did matter that would mean the weight gradients should be averaged for MSE and summed for SSE in mini-batch gradient descent?

Comment: seems at least a partial dup of [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/20377/2444). let me know.

Comment: hi, I've seen that one before. I don't think it answers my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you stated looks correct :-

The SSE loss function includes the summation of the errors in the other training examples of the mini-batch (each training example's loss in the mini-batch is summed for one big loss)
SSE = Summation of (y-y')squared for all samples in mini-batch

The MSE loss function averages the loss of each individual training example in the mini-batch, and then all those losses are averaged based on the mini-batch size.
MSE = (1/m)SSE

Comment: You can format the formulas and math symbols in this answer with latex. I would recommend that you do that.